# Shell: Remove last character of line if it is double quote

Tags: sh

How can I remove the last character of line if the last character is a single quote?

example:

```
'This is'
a text book
'John's car'
```

expected output

```
'This is
a text book
'John's car
```

I am using Solaris and ksh.

Comment: if the **last** character in the line is a single quote you can try: `sed "s/'$//g" <file>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a basic substitution that you can do with `sed`:

```
sed "s/'$//" input
```